# Attempting to merge duplicate rows together, error on max specified more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with a bunch of entries, and some of the entries might look like:

```
| id | name | field1 | field2 | field3 |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | id1  | 2      | 3      |        |
| 2  | id2  | 2      | 1      |        |
| 3  | id1  |        |        | 5      |
| 4  | id2  |        |        | 8      |
```

I'm trying to run this following SQL statement to merge similar rows together, and place them back in the table:

```
SELECT name, max(id), max(field1), max(field2), max(field3) INTO groups FROM groups GROUP BY name;
```

Which I was hoping would give me:

```
| id | name | field1 | field2 | field3 |
----------------------------------------
| 3  | id1  | 2      | 3      | 5      |
| 4  | id2  | 2      | 1      | 8      |
```

But this statement just gives me `ERROR:  column "max" specified more than once`

What is wrong with my statement here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You must specify an alias to each `max` call.

Comment: `select .. into ..` should not be used any more to create a new table. It's better to use `create table as select ...`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you have used is improper, as `select ... into ...` creates a new table. You want to update or delete rows in the existing table. You can do it using a common table expression:

```
with new_rows as (
    select 
        name, 
        max(id) as id, 
        max(field1) as field1, 
        max(field2) as field2, 
        max(field3) as field3
    from groups 
    group by name
),
deleted_rows as (
    delete from groups
    where id not in (
        select id 
        from new_rows
        )
    )
update groups g
set field1 = n.field1, field2 = n.field2, field3 = n.field3
from new_rows n
where n.id = g.id
returning g.*;

 id | name | field1 | field2 | field3 
----+------+--------+--------+--------
  3 | id1  |      2 |      3 |      5
  4 | id2  |      2 |      1 |      8
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just needs to take out the `INTO xxx` from your query, and alias your columns, so that you can later distinguish them:

```
-- Aliasing columns
SELECT 
    name, max(id) AS id, max(field1) AS field1, max(field2) AS field2, max(field3) AS field3
FROM 
    groups 
GROUP BY 
    name;
```

... and you get

```
name | id | field1 | field2 | field3
:--- | -: | -----: | -----: | -----:
id1  |  3 |      2 |      3 |      5
id2  |  4 |      2 |      1 |      8
```

*Check everything at dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4351c90d228da9038f3bd898ca131090)*

---

As mentioned by **klin** in his/her answer, `SELECT INTO` creates a new table, and, without column aliasing, several columns would be called `max`. See [PostgreSQL SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html)